How to call Razorpay PaymentResultListener inside the compose screen
How to call Razorpay PaymentResultListener from compose code?
PaymentResultListener {
    override fun onPaymentSuccess(p0: String?) {
        // Handle payment success
        Log.d("Payment", "Payment successful: $p0")
    }

    override fun onPaymentError(p0: Int, p1: String?) {
        // Handle payment error
        Log.e("Payment", "Payment error: $p0 - $p1")
    }
}

